# Meaning of "So say the knights who say NIH"

Tags: idiomatic-language, metaphors, reference

> So say the knights who say NIH.

I don't get the above reference. What does it mean?

Comment: Why the downvote? If you believe this belongs somewhere else, please explain it in the comments.

Comment: Probably because you don’t show any indication that you tried to find an answer before you asked. See our [Help Center's "How to Ask" page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Or because you didn’t include where you came across this sentence so that people could give you a proper answer about whether “nih” is a typo or intentional. See also [Details, Please....](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439), [Why you should cite your source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/), and [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783) on meta.

Comment: Asking about a *reference* has nothing to do with English. Do you have a question about the *syntax* of the sentence?

Comment: @JasonBassford it’s ok to ask about meaning especially when the words seem to mean something other than the sum of their definitions. It’s not ok to not explain what about the words and where you found them made it hard to understand the meaning.

Comment: @ColleenV It would be fine if the question was *What does NIH mean?* Or if a particular *aspect* of the sentence were questioned. But neither of those things were done. There is no clear indication what the *source* of the confusion is. Instead, it asks for the *reference*.

Comment: @JasonBassford we agree, I just wanted to point out that it doesn’t have to be syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a reference to the movie *Monty Python and the Holy Grail*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_Who_Say_%22Ni!%22

Comment: Would you consider the "H" at the end a typo ?

Comment: A typo, perhaps, or someone simply wrote it as they were trying to transcribe a word that was spoken in a movie. The accepted spelling over the past 40+ years is "Ni!" but, if someone has only seen the movie, they may not know that.

Comment: My first thought was that it could be a pun on the NIH (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institutes_of_Health)  in the right context, but it's probably just a typo.

Comment: Or a transcription error mistaking the final exclamation point (which is absolutely required) for an "h".

Comment: In [the context](https://forum.minetest.net/viewtopic.php?p=346796) this was said in, it is a pun where LMD is accused of continuely reinventing the wheel. NIH is an acronym which means [Not Invented Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here)